# Broken Count>0 Error

Tags: package-management

I got this message saying the system package is broken and I may have third party repositories. However, I checked and there are no third party repositories. I went in a terminal and typed apt-get install -f and got "unable to lock administration file, are you root? What does that mean? Also I have not installed anything the error message just appeared one day.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Your command `apt-get install -f` has to be run from an administration/root account which is why you got the error.  enter it with `sudo apt-get install -f` where `sudo` will elevate your privileges briefly to 'root' for the command that follows sudo.

Comment: Thank you the error sign has disappeared. Worked just like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `apt install -f` from elevated privileges... You can accomplish this by using a root shell by running `sudo` in front of `apt install -f`. This should promptly fix your issue, leave a comment if any more problems occur.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
unable to lock administration file, are you root?
```

is becuase you are not `root`, so `apt` can't get a lock on the files it needs, which makes sense, as you only want people with `sudo` access to install and remove apps, or else any user could install a virus or something else that breaks the system.

So, the solution is:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

and be sure to read the output before pressing `y`, as sometimes it deletes something you want.

**TL;DR: use sudo**